# Angular Webpack setup: Migrate from css to sass using webpack

Tags: javascript, css, angular, webpack, sass

I fear this question might be too broad, but I am hoping to get some help in terms of my webpack setup.

I have a large MEAN stack setup with Angular. The solution is currently functionally working with an Webpack build.

Till now I have used plain css files, which are referenced by Angular in the Component declaration, for example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'something',
  templateUrl: 'template',
  styleUrls: ['some_component_style.css', 'other.css']
})
```

However I plan to migrate all my css files to sass files in the future, however I am a little unsure of how I set this up in Webpack.

Here is my current webpack configs:

webpack.config.common.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'app': './assets/app/main.ts'
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts']
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [{ loader: 'html-loader' }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/, // for legacy purposes
                use: [{ loader: 'raw-loader' }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
                }, {
                    loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
                }, {
                    loader: "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|tff|eot|ico)$/,
                use: [{ loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]' }]
            }
        ],
    exprContextCritical: false
    }
};
```

webpack.config.dev.js:

```
var path = require('path');

var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.config.common.js');

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname + '/public/js/app'),
        publicPath: "/js/app/",
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: [
                    {loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader', options: {
                        transpileOnly: true
                    }},
                    {loader: 'angular2-template-loader'},
                    {loader: 'angular-router-loader'}
                ]
            }
        ]

    }
});
```

webpack.config.prod.js:

```
const AngularCompilerPlugin = require('@ngtools/webpack').AngularCompilerPlugin;

var path = require('path');

var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.config.common.js');

module.exports = webpackMerge.smart(commonConfig, {
    entry: {
        'app': './assets/app/main.aot.ts'
    },

    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname + '/public/js/app'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/js/app/',
        chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].chunk.js'
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /(?:\.ngfactory\.js|\.ngstyle\.js|\.ts)$/,
                loader: '@ngtools/webpack'
            },
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: [
                    'awesome-typescript-loader',
                    'angular2-template-loader',
                    'angular-router-loader?aot=true'
                ]
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            sourceMap: false
        }),
        new AngularCompilerPlugin({
            tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json',
            entryModule: './assets/app/app.module#AppModule',
            sourceMap: true
        })
    ]
});
```

and my build scripts from package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "build": "del-cli public/js/app && webpack --config webpack.config.dev.js --progress --profile --watch",
    "build:prod": "del-cli public/js/app && ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js --progress --profile --bail && del-cli 'public/js/app/**/*.js' 'public/js/app/**/*.js.map' '!public/js/app/bundle.js' '!public/js/app/*.chunk.js' 'assets/app/**/*.*.ngfactory.ts' 'assets/app/**/*.shim.ts' 'assets/app/**/*.ngsummary.json' 'assets/app/**/*.ngstyle.ts'",
  },
```

I am aware that setting up the solution with sass, might benefit a lot from having a whole different structure. I have worked with solutions that didn't use the 'styleUrls' angular tag for example, since the sass wasn't set up for this. But only generated a large css file for the whole site. I guess this is the sort of 'keep in mind' for this question, but the main question is:

How do I migrate from using css files to sass files with webpack? (I am using webpack 3.x)

Comment: I'm not fluent on angular, but i can say that your webpack config for scss/css is ok, you would just need `extract-text-webpack-plugin` to extract your css from your bundles to real css files. I'm missing something else from your question, but i think it is more relate to angular than webpack

Comment: Ideally I actually want to migrate away from using the angular styling declarations. It is useful, but I prefer to have the sass setup separate from Angular components. The Angular styling declarations has it's uses in isolating css to specific components - I think this is smart for css files. The usage that sass can bring to the project, can benefit a lot from having the sass code entirely separate from the Angular code. I appreciate the tip, and will test with that plugin as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your webpack config is fine.

You can always have a mix of global scss AND component scss, as you say Angular styling declarations isolate the css (or scss) for each component and this is a feature you want.

But if you want to have global styling in addition, this is what you can do:

create a styles.scss in /src/styles/ folder

From your app.module.ts (the root module of your project), just import the scss file like this (choose the correct path obviously):

```
import '../styles/styles.scss';
```

And now you can use styles.scss to import other scss (or css) files that will be applied globally to your project.

As an example this is what I have in my project inside styles.scss:

```
@import '_bootstrap_settings.scss';
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import '~c3/c3';

// Angular Material Theme
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink";

@import 'variables';
```